# ending the scope of <C-r> in vim

Tags: vim

I am trying to write a map in `vim` as:

```
:inoremap `foo ! Program <CR>! Author     :<C-R>=$USER <CR>! Date      :<C-R>=strftime("%c")<CR>
```

with , I am expecting a line break, so the expected output is:

```
! Program 
! Author     :rudra
! Date      :Sat 14 Jun 2014 19:16:33 BST
```

But what I am getting is:

```
! Program 
! Author     :rudra! Date      :Sat 14 Jun 2014 19:16:33 BST
```

i.e. no linebreak from the 2nd `<CR>` .
Kindly help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two `<CR>` after `<C-R>` one to end `<C-R>` and one to insert an actual carriage return (or line break).

```
:inoremap `foo ! Program <CR>! Author     :<C-R>=$USER <CR><CR>! Date      :<C-R>=strftime("%c")<CR>
```